# Is StackOverflow.com powered by an specific Q&A / FAQ provider?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10369/which-tools-and-technologies-build-the-stack-exchange-network)

I'm interested in implementing a cool, dynamic, interactive FAQ / Q&A solution for a .Net site and really like how StackOverflow manages these on its website. Is SO powered by an Q&A provider, openSource solution or is it an in-house build solution?

Comment: In-house. Good news: you can propose an argument to become part of the Stack Exchange world: http://area51.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 4):

It is an in house solution.

The [ServerFault blog](http://blog.serverfault.com/) does discuss internals every now and then.

You may also find [Which tools and technologies build the Stack Exchange Network?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10369/140505) to be an interesting read.